# command line count number of defined files in all subfolders

Tags: windows, cmd, command-line

I have `N` different directories (titles are random and do not have `test` pattern in string)

```
C:\Folder\test1\file.txt
C:\Folder\test2\file.txt
...
C:\Folder\testN\file.txt
```

I want using the command line to count number of `file.txt` files in `Folder` dir in all `test1`..`testN` subdirectories, for example `C:\Folder\*\file.txt`

Could you please help?

Comment: Help suggests that more than one party is doing some of the work, your part is to write the code, ours is to help you to fix it if it doesn't work as intended. You need to start by cycling through all of the matching `file.txt` files within the `Folder` structure. Then you need to incorporate a method of counting each of those returned files. There are several methods of achieving both of those things, and whichever, I offer, there'd be a duplicate question here already. I would suggest that you use the search facility at the top of the page, and adapt an answer to suit your particular task.

Comment: I used to use python module glob for that task -  to write input request in one line. I wonder if I can do it in command line, because there is no "/*/" option in cmd... I started with dir /b /a-d | find /v /c "?" command, but not sure how I can use loop. I need to have my request in one line, avoiding batch files, because I will use it on remote connection.... I believe my question is very standard, but I was not able to google it, so if you could help me that would be great...

Comment: You don't need Google, or any other/better search engine, the search facility available at the top of each page of this site, _(as you've already been told by both commentors)_, is all you require.

Comment: I search, but did not find useful content, in general only batch files, which I dont need. Could you please guide me in right direction?